# cp recursive with specific file extension

Tags: command-line, bash, cp

I am trying to copy all `.odt` files including those in subdirectories.

```
cp -r ~/Documents/* ~/copies # works as expected
```

```
cp -r ~/Documents/*.odt ~/copies # does not work as expected
```

The first line will copy all files and in all subdirectories but the second will copy only the `.odt` files in `~/Documents` and none of the files in the subdirectories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to **replicate the directory structure** (more like what `cp -r` does as suggested by steeldriver) but only populate it with the `.odt` files, you can do it with `rsync`, where `-f` is the 'filter' option. The other options are more straight-forward. You find all the options in `man rsync`.

```
rsync -nvr -f '+ *.odt' -f '+ **/' -f '- *' --prune-empty-dirs ~/Documents/ ~/copies/
```

It is a good idea to use the 'dry run' option `-n` and the verbose option `-v` in order to see what will be done before running the real command (when `n` is removed from the command line).

Comment: Really nice words from a real command line guru. Thanks @steeldriver :-)

Comment: That looks like its going to work for me. Although I would like to exclude some directories, but I am not having luck ```rsync -vr -f '+ *.odt' -f '+ **/' -f '- *' --prune-empty-dirs --exclude-from='~/Documents/dir/dirdir/list_of_exclusions.txt' ~/Documents/ ~/copies``` ```rsync: failed to open exclude file``` ```No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at exclude.c(1207) [client=3.1.3]```

Comment: @Insideup I don't think rsync is going to expand `~` in the `--exclude-from` option. You'll have to expand that yourself, or use `$HOME` and double quotes instead of single there. As it is, it's looking for `./~/Documents/dir/...`. That's why it can't find it.

Comment: @JoL Yes, thank you, that worked.  Also used full paths in the exclude file, but that is not working ```/home/namename/Documents/dir_to_exclude```

Comment: @Insideup How absolute paths are interpreted is specified in the `rsync(1)` manpage section titled `INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES` in the first point that begins "if the pattern starts with a / then it is anchored to a particular  spot  in  the  hierarchy  of files, otherwise it is matched against the end of the pathname.  This is similar to a leading ^ in  regular  expressions.  Thus /foo would match a name of "foo" at either the "root of the transfer" (for a global rule)  or  in the  merge-file's  directory (for a per-directory rule)."

Comment: @Insideup See, the issue lies in that any rsync operation implies both a source and a destination. Is the absolute path supposed to be in the source or the destination? It seems they opted for neither and going instead for the root of the transfer. That seems more useful to me. I'm not sure what "merge-file" refers to, though.

Comment: I was not able to get the exclusion file to work.  As a workaround, I'm deleting things directly in the script afterwards.

Comment: @Insideup, what about adding a filter or set of filters for what you want to exclude: `rsync -nvr -f '+ *.odt' -f '+ **/' -f '- full-path-to/dir-to-exclude' -f '- *' --prune-empty-dirs ~/Documents/ ~/copies/` ? This can be done via a file if there are many dirs to exclude. -- I have not tested it, maybe switch order between `'+ **/'` and `'- full-path-to/dir-to-exclude'`

Comment: @sudodus Thanks, I may give that a try.

Answer (score 17):

You can either let the (bash) shell do the recursion instead:

```
shopt -s globstar
cp -nt ~/copies/ ~/Documents/**/*.odt
```

or use the `find` command

```
find ~/Documents -name '*.odt' -exec cp -nt ~/copies/ {} +
```

The former may exceed the system's `ARG_MAX` limits if the number if files is very large, whereas the latter will break the command up to stay within `ARG_MAX`.

I added the `-n` option to prevent "clobbering" files with the same name.

Comment: @Insideup you're welcome - I should have mentioned that the above copies each file into the top-level of `~/copies`. If you want to replicate the directory structure (more like what `cp -r` does) but only populate it with the `.odt` files, that would probably be best handled using the `rsync` command.