# gNote Ignoring Directory Sync After Fresh Reinstallation of Ubuntu

Tags: sync, gnote

According to the good folks over at gnome, the default and only version of gnote available for Ubuntu 20.04 is gnote 3.36.0.  [And it is too old for them to provide support for](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnote/-/issues/114), therefore the ubuntu team can address my current gnote issue:

I am using Gnote Version 3.36.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.  I have a hybrid SSD/HHD machine with my home folder set as the hhd partition.

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and updated ubuntu/grub to recognize my /home partition where all of my files settings are.

Upon re-installation of gnote the majority of my notes are missing. Gnote is only reading notes from the default location.

`~/.local/share/gnote`

And ignores all of the notes that I have at `~/Documents/gnotes`.

The Note Directory Watcher and the Local Directory Sync Service plugins are both active, and in preferences gnote shows the location of my `~/Documents/gnotes` folder, but still simply ignores the notes present in the directory.

I thought the issue may have been corrupt config files, so I used synaptic to completely remove gnote (all config files) and reinstall it.  I reset the configuration to recognize my local directory of gnotes, but again gnote ignores the directory and will not sync.

**Note:** I have been looking for a way to install gnote 40rc or later on ubuntu 20.04 since I read that it fixes a lot of sync issues.  However, I have not been successful.
Can someone tell me how to either:

a.) fix my Gnote Version 3.36.0 to recognize & sync the notes that are present

or

b.) update my Gnote Version 3.36.0 to 40rc on ubuntu 20.04 so that I can successfully sync my notes.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally came up with a workaround.

I used the find command solution found here:
[cp recursive with specific file extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300558/cp-recursive-with-specific-file-extension)  to copy all of my notes from the my local sync directory at `~/Documents/Gnote` to my default gnote storage folder at `~/.local/share/gnote`

`find ~/Documents/Gnotes -name '*.note' -exec cp -nt ~/.local/share/gnote {} +`

And then, to avoid this situation in the future, I used this nifty little bash script to convert all of my gnotes to plain text:

https://github.com/rhoconlinux/gnote-massive-export-to-txt

From there I simply copied the notes in my `~/NEXTCLOUD/Notes` directory and now I can do away with qnotes and use NC and/or others apps like https://www.qownnotes.org/